A hard optimization problem
Consider the following function, for $1\leq j \leq N$
$$\tag{1}
y_j=\sum_{k=0}^{M} \frac{e^{-\sum_{|i|\leq k}(k-|i|)x_{j+i}/v}-e^{-\sum_{|i|\leq k}(k+1-|i|)x_{j+i}/v}}{\sum_{|i|\leq k} x_{j+i}}
$$
for some fixed $N,M,v>0$. To avoid repetition, take $M< N/2$, and assume the indexes are periodic modulo $N$. How do I invert this expression?
Motivation: I have data on $\{y_j\}$ and I want to approximate $\{x_j\}$ that best fits the data. As an analytical inversion of $(1)$ seems hard, what would be the best way of fitting $\{y_j\}$?
Some thoughts: $y_j$ is, in some sense, a function of convolutions, and I have found a relatively fast way of numerically computing $y_j$, discussed here. However, I am not entirely sure how to iteratively update $\{x_j\}$ to get a better and more efficient approximation to the real data $\{y_j\}$. A numerical fitting algorithm is also being discussed here. I am wondering whether we can do something about it analytically. Any thoughts?

Your equation can be expressed in the form $y=F(x)$ where $y=(y_1,\dots,y_N)$ and $x=(x_1,\dots,x_N)$, i.e., in the form $y_j=F_j(x_1,\dots,x_N)$.  Here $F$ is the complicated expression you have written above.
You say that you are given $y$ and want to find $x$.  A straightforward approach is to solve the optimization problem
$$\min_x \|y - F(x)\|_2^2$$
using any optimization algorithm of your choice (e.g., gradient descent, Newton's method, etc.).  Whether it works well or not is an empirical matter; you'd have to try it and see.  The initialization for $x$ in the optimization algorithm might matter.
